# Get original created date of PDF from URL

Tags: php, url, date, pdf

I am working with the pdf at the end of this URL

```
https://www2.blackrock.com/webcore/litService/search/getDocument.seam?venue=PUB_INS&source=CONTENT&serviceName=PublicServiceView&ContentID=51648
```

By viewing it, we can see that it's the `12/31/2012` edition. Is there a way that I can get some timestamp data on the pdf itself? Upload date, created date, modified date, anything in that ballpark?

I have tried the following and both return `12/31/1969`

```
$pdfURL = 'https://www2.blackrock.com/webcore/litService/search/getDocument.seam?venue=PUB_INS&source=CONTENT&serviceName=PublicServiceView&ContentID=51648';
$rawPDF = file_get_contents($pdfURL);
echo date("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($pdfURL));

-AND-

echo date("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($rawPDF));
```

I have also tried

```
$headerArray = array();
$headerArray = get_headers($pdfURL, 1);
echo "<PRE>";
var_dump($headerArray);
echo "</PRE>";
```

However `Last-Modified` doesn't exist in the header array

Comment: Is [this article] helpful in your case? [this article]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326604/get-file-creation-date-over-http

Comment: I think that would work, but I'm not entirely sure how I would utilize that with php. Guess I'll have to do some research

Comment: There's a PHP function [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) use it then iterate over table that is returned and look for `Last-Modified`

Comment: For that URL there isn't a "last-modified".

Comment: I can't access this url so i can't tell, but from what i saw on my own site, Last-modified field is available for directly accessible files (like where i hovered over a link and there was real path to a .PDF at the end), whereas for files dispensed from a script i couldn't find it (like where i have download.php?link=file.pdf

Comment: Are you not located in the US? I'm not sure I know what you mean by "hover over the URL". I would also say throw you next response in an answer instead of a comment so that I can at least give you a green for the help you've given

Comment: No, I'n not from US. And hover over an ULR means with your mouse when the page is displayed, browsers give me info in some little popup at the bottom where this url is leading. Sorry I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered previously and because i provided only a link, moderator deleted my answer and converted to a comment. Let's try now with more complete answer based on our comments:

From what I have analyzed, the HTTP header for a given link contains Last-modified field. But only if a link is directly to a file. However when you see that a link is the sort of `somepage.pgp?file=file.pdf` kind, Last-modified won't be there.
In the first case, php function `get_headers()` can be used, to read the field in question. I the latter case I'm afraid i cannot help you.